# How do I group data in Oracle SQL without using GROUP BY OR PARTITION BY

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, aggregate-functions, gaps-and-islands

My data is like this

MY_TABLE

| DATE | CUSTOMER_ID | FAC_NUM | MONIES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/Jan/2020 | 12345678 | ABC123 | 125000 |
| 02/Jan/2020 | 12345678 | ABC123 | 125000 |
| 03/Jan/2020 | 12345678 | ABC123 | 125000 |
| 01/Feb/2020 | 12345678 | ABC123 | 143000 |
| 02/Feb/2020 | 12345678 | ABC123 | 143000 |
| 03/Feb/2020 | 12345678 | ABC123 | 143000 |
| 04/Feb/2020 | 12345678 | ABC123 | 143000 |
| 05/Feb/2020 | 12345678 | ABC123 | 143000 |
| 01/Mar/2020 | 12345678 | ABC123 | 125000 |
| 02/Mar/2020 | 12345678 | ABC123 | 125000 |
| 03/Mar/2020 | 12345678 | ABC123 | 125000 |
| 04/Mar/2020 | 12345678 | ABC123 | 125000 |

I want the output to be like this

| CUSTOMER_ID | FAC_NUM | MONIES | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345678 | ABC123 | 125000 | 01/Jan/2020 | 03/JAN/2020 |
| 12345678 | ABC123 | 143000 | 01/Feb/2020 | 05/Feb/2020 |
| 12345678 | ABC123 | 125000 | 01/Mar/2020 | 04/Mar/2020 |

I have tried using the following

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID
      ,FAC_NUM
      ,MONIES
      ,MIN(DATE) AS START_DATE
      ,MAX(DATE) AS END_DATE
FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID
      ,FAC_NUM
      ,MONIES
```

However, the output I get with this approach is as follows (this is not the desired output)

| CUSTOMER_ID | FAC_NUM | MONIES | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345678 | ABC123 | 125000 | 1 Jan 2020 | 4 Mar 2020 |
| 12345678 | ABC123 | 143000 | 1 Feb 2020 | 5 Feb 2020 |

Is there a way to obtain the output I am looking for without using PL/SQL (I need to run this query over a huge dataset)? If not, what would be the most efficient way to do this using PL/SQL?

I am new to stackoverflow and SQL. Your support would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,
Ani

Answer (score 2):

Instead of "I want output", it would probably helped if you *described* what you wanted.

To me, it looks as if you'd want to group additionally by month, e.g. your query slightly modified:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID
      ,FAC_NUM
      ,MONIES
      ,MIN(DATE) AS START_DATE
      ,MAX(DATE) AS END_DATE
FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID
      ,FAC_NUM
      ,MONIES
      , to_char(date, 'yyyymm')      --> this
```

Of course, `date` column name is invalid; it is reserved for `date` datatype so I presume it is, actually, named differently.

Comment: I believe you can use `DATE` as a column name if it's quoted every time it's used.

Comment: Certainly, @Bob. But the fact that you *can* do it doesn't mean that you *should* do it. Besides, there's no evidence - in OP's message - that they used double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

This reads like a gaps-and-islands problem. Islands are adjacent rows having the same customer, fac num and amount. Whenever the amount changes, a new group starts.

Here is one approach using the difference between row numbers to identify the islands:

```
select customer_id, fac_num, monies,
    min(date) as start_date, max(date) as end_date
from (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by customer_id, fac_num order by date) as rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by customer_id, fac_num, monies order by date) as rn2
    from mytable t
) t
group by customer_id, fac_num, monies, rn1 - rn2
order by customer_id, fac_num, min(start_date)
```

Comment: Thank you @GMB. This solution solved the problem.

Comment: this solution is not working when there are two consecutive islands with same new monies. In such scenarios, it treats both the island as one. Is there a way to solve this?